# Make a function return the same type of a overriden base class method

Tags: python-typing

I have an abstract base class `MyClass` which contains an abstract method `get_type` which returns a class type.

I also have a funtion `fn` which expects an instance of `MyClass` and I want to typing the return of `fn` as an instance of the same type returned by its overriden `get_type` `arg` argument.

For example, in this code below, I want intellisense to show the type of `my_fraction` as `Fraction` (not `MyFractionSubclass` or `Type[Fraction]`) and `my_decimal` as `Decimal` (not `MyDecimalSubclass` or `Type[Decima]`), but both are being evaluated as `Any`

```py
from abc import ABC
from decimal import Decimal
from fractions import Fraction
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


class MyClass(ABC):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def get_type(cls) -> Type[T]:
        ...


class MyDecimalSubclass(MyClass):
    @classmethod
    def get_type(cls):
        return Decimal


class MyFractionSubclass(MyClass):
    @classmethod
    def get_type(cls):
        return Fraction


def fn(arg: MyClass):
    value = arg.get_type()("100")
    return value


my_fraction = fn(MyFractionSubclass())  # should be of type `Fraction`
my_decimal = fn(MyDecimalSubclass())  # should be of type `Decimal`

print(my_fraction, my_decimal)
```

Note: there will be another subclasses of `MyClass`

I tried a naive (maybe stupid) solution like this one but didn't worked ("of course not"):

```py
def fn(arg: MyClass) -> "arg.get_type()()":
    value = arg.get_type()("100")
    return value
```

I also tried a hundred times with ChatGPT but it couldn't provide a solution

Comment: Something like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=decee66e90745ac14eac03227dc82ac6)? You need `MyClass` generic to make `fn` typed (and for semantics, of course), and restrictions on `T` to make `arg.get_type()("100")` possible (I'm using enumeration above, you can write a protocol instead to be even more correct - similar to [this one](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=df00e67d61538ee8cc8985b0857e9fb2)).

Comment: That is exactly what I need! Thanks a lot! I also realized that it works without the need of using subclasses like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=3f20d212e78f02a77950f04cd76f9357)

Comment: It works, but please avoid using type hints information at run time - this may break unexpectedly in case of complex annotations or (esp. important) string-based annotations + `if TYPE_CHECKING` import, which is a common case (suppose I have done `if TYPE_CHECKING: from x import X` and then `fn(MyClass['X']('100'))`). You *really* don't want to mix type annotations and runtime execution, unless you're as big as `pydantic` and can afford strict rules for users to obey.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I put validations for the concrete type in my use so the usages of `Repository` fails if the correct type was not provided. But now I'm awared

Comment: @SUTerliakov I changed my solution based on your comments. Check it [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=50df0db9e2637004652baeab3b853b8d) again please. I don't know why mypy `revel_type()` didn't worked but intellisense worked in PyCharm